# Many rails Models with the same flag. What's the best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, data-modeling, models

One of mine rails projects has many models with the same flag: approved.
I don't like to manage the flag 'approved' for so many models, and I am seeking a DRY solution.
I have found some plugin like flag_shih_tzu or can_flag, but I think they work only with a model.

Do you know some plugin to flag many models at once ?
I think that I a good solution (without plugin) should use the polymorphic associations, do you agree ?

many thanks,
Alessandro

Comment: refactoring for a mere column seems a bit overkill. Using polymorphic association sounds weird: what do you want to refactor there? Stick to the KISS :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: I agree with you !
Actually I am recreating the project in Rails3, there are a lots of things I hate in it.
One of these is "5 different tables with the flag field 'approved' "

Comment: If they are indeed disparate models, then separate 'approved' fields is perfectly legitimate. You don't need to twist your code into a pretzel in order to satisfy DRY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a way to store all the functions in a single place, but have them accessible from all your flagable models, I'd recommend writing a mixin for them.  For example, in lib/approved.rb, you could have the module:

```
module Approved

    # Any approval functions/constants that don't belong in a model go here...

    module Mixin
        def self.included(klass)
            klass.class_eval do
                # Class-levell model macros can be run here
                named_scope :approved,   {:conditions => {:approved => true}}
                named_scope :unapproved, {:conditions => {:approved => false}}
            end
        end

        def approved?
            return (self.approved == true)
        end

        # Other shared model functions go here...
    end
end
```

And then it's just a matter of including the mixin in all the models that need those functions:

```
class Approvable < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Approved::Mixin

    # etc.
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: We both deserve a high-five for being equally awesome =)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem in my application, we have 10 or so models that all require approval and didn't want to copy the code everywhere. In our case we are using `transitions` as our workflow gem, so instead of having a flag `approved` we have a string column `state`.

A model that requires approval looks like this:

```
class Comment < A:RB
  include ApprovalWorkflow
end
```

Then we have a workflow that looks like this:

```
# /app/workflows/approval_workflow.rb
module ApprovalWorkflow
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      state_machine do
        .. workflow junk goes here .. 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So what's going on here is that we've created a module, which you can think of like an anonymous piece of code which does't belong anywhere (read more about modules to understand why this is an awful description), which we then include in our classes which mixes in the functionality. Now our comment class has the approval workflow!

In you case, assuming you were to keep the approval flag, you might add default validations, some methods like `approve!(user)` or scopes for querying.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yup - +1 for shared awesomeness.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using polymorphic associations is not the solution unless they are all the same base object. Keep in mind that with inheritance the parent should have an is-a relationship with the child.

What you could do is create an `Approval` model and have a one-to-one relationship with the approvable models.